# How to Tell Which Pages Aren't Hit in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp-classic

I have a legacy Classic ASP application as well as some .NET pages that has thousands of pages overall and I know for a fact that a good number of them are no longer used/depreciated that should be removed in an effort to clean up the codebase. They are hosted under IIS, and I was just wondering how I can go about finding out which pages are not hit so I could safely remove them.

Answer (score 4):

Use log parser to find which pages exists in your system and again use logParser to find which pages are hit in your system. Find their differences for depreciated pages.

1. [Which Pages Exists in your System](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/forensic-log-parsing-microsofts-logparser)

   logparser -i:FS "SELECT Path from c:\inetpub\wwwroot*.* ORDER BY Path
2. [Which Pages are hit in your Application](https://mlichtenberg.wordpress.com/2011/02/03/log-parser-rocks-more-than-50-examples/)

   logparser "select cs-uri-stem from [LogFileName] where cs-uri-stem like ‘%aspx%’ or cs-uri-stem like ‘%ashx%’ group by cs-uri-stem order by cs-uri-stem"
3. These will generate you two different lists. Import them to database (SQL Server) and use following query

   SELECT Path FROM PAGES_EXISTS

   EXCEPT

   SELECT Path FROM PAGES_HIT

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look in the log files to see which pages are /hit/ and based on that, keep that pages that are active.

Answer (score 0):

Log parsing seems like the painful way to do this.  If you can afford to collect a few more months of data, add an subroutine in your classic asp pages to log each page to a sql db and update the counts.   Might be useful because in the end you will be writing 301 redirects if you remove those pages.

Answer (score 0):

If they aren't in the log it doesn't neccesarily mean they are unused (ASP has includes) - I would create an index for all the ASP pages (using something like Lucene), then do a search for each file - if there are no hits, it's a safe bet it isn't used. You could also check the last access time on the file system (if that's working on your server - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).